# What pronoun to use in place of "en qqn"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

I'm trying to translate the phrase "I didn't connect with him" or "I didn't connect with them," as in "We didn't see eye to eye."

I'm doing this with the phrase "se reconnaitre en quelqu'un", and I've gotten this far:

> Je ne me suis pas reconnu....

But I don't know what pronoun to use (or where to put it) in place of *en qqn.* Should it just be *en lui* at the end of the sentence?

Moreover, where would *vraiment* go if I wanted to say "I didn't really connect with him" ?

> Je ne me suis vraiment pas reconnu.... ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a case where you could use `reconnu`to render connection in a way a little bit different from the way you tought you could use it.

A retired father sees his son working in the farm, and it seems to him he is seeing himself as he was 30 years ago for example. The father would then say `Je me suis reconnu en lui`. To give another illustration, a Shaolin monk accompanies his students to Paris Bercy Omnisport for a martial art demonstration and is amazed to see one of them perfom exactly as he would, he would say: `je me suis reconnu en lui`

Now for what you want to say, you may say `Je ne me suis pas entendu avec lui`to say I did not connect with him and `Je ne me suis pas entendu avec eux`for I did not connect with them. And you would say `Je ne me suis pas vraiment entendu avec lui/eux`to say I did not really connect with them.

You can also say `Je n'étais pas [vraiment] au diapason avec lui/eux` meaning we did not agree. You may also say `Je n'étais pas [vraiment] en phase avec lui/eux`

Comment: +1, surtout pour "au diapason." A very cool image to capture being connected/in harmony with someone, imo!

Answer (score 2):

With "se reconnaitre," I’d use “en” with pronouns: “en lui”/”en eux”; but “dans” with nouns "dans cette personne"/"dans ces gens".

Regardless, I think the negation of "s’entendre [très bien avec]” would best capture “don’t connect with” because frankly I often don’t connect well with people in whom I see [too much of] myself.

For the placement of “vraiment,” I'd put it instead after the "pas," which I think better captures the nuance between "didn't really" and "really didn't" that I feel exists in English (and again, I’d probably prefer “s’entendre”: “Je ne me suis pas vraiment entendu [très bien] avec lui/eux).”